# Adding Text to Video with ffmpeg in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I am trying to add text to a video using ffmpeg package but it returns an error i.e. Return Code 1
Here's my code.

```
  final videoPath = _controller.file.path;
  final outputName = videoPath.hashCode.toString();

  final output =
        File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$outputName.mp4');

  String command =
        "-y -i $videoPath -filter_complex '[0]scale=540:-1[s];[s]drawtext=fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/Download/SuperDessert.ttf:text='MY_TEXT':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2' ${output.path}";

  final session = await FFmpegKit.execute(command);

  final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

  if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
    log("Success full text added");
  } else {
    log("Error adding text: ${await session.getFailStackTrace()}");
  }
```

I have tried changing the output directory, changed `fontfile` to `font`

Comment: please post the error log.

Comment: @Zahra session.getFailStackTrace() is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use fonts rather than default then do use **FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectoryList** function.

```
FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectoryList(["/system/fonts", "/System/Library/Fonts", "<folder with fonts>"]);
```